# socket.io: One-off command/message to all clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I'm using Node.js, Express and socket.io.

I would like to send a one-off command/message to all connected socket.io clients (e.g. reload all connected clients/web browsers).

Some relevant, minimal sample code:

**Client side code**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io();

socket.on('reload', function(msg){
  //location.reload();
  console.log("Reloading page!");
});
</script>
```

**Server side code**:

```
/**
 * app.js
 */

var express = require('express'),
    socket = require('./routes/socket');

var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

// Hook Socket.io into Express
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);

// Setting up redis adapter
// See: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#sending-messages-from-the-outside-world
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));

// ... snip ... 

// Nothing of relevance or substance in ./routes/socket.js
io.sockets.on('connection', socket);

// Start server
http.listen(3001, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

**More server side code:**

This is the the one-off command to run via something like `$ node reloadclients.js`:

```
/**
 * reloadclients.js
 */

var io = require('socket.io-emitter')({'host': 'localhost', 'port': 6379});
io.emit('reload', "now");
```

---

This seems to work fine. However, when I run `node reloadclients.js`, I would like to terminate the script once emit has successfully run (at the moment it continues running even after the script has seemingly worked). How do you go about doing this? Calling `process.exit();` after `io.emit('reload', "now");` seems to result in premature termination (where the clients don't get reloaded). I would like to terminate the `reloadclients.js` script only if the `emit()` invocation is successful.

Any thoughts on how to approach this? Is there a better way? I'd be happy to listen to any feedback :)

Comment: Since `io.emit` method doesn't support a callback function (it throws "Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting" message) you can't detect receiving a message by all clients. You may try exiting script in 1 sec after emitting via `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks @Curious. This is what I ended up doing (i.e. waiting several seconds and hoping for the best! hehe)